# How to achieve different output with the same selector in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

child component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="variable1===true">
  Container 1
</div>

<div *ngIf="variable2===true">
   Container 2
</div>
```

child component.ts

```
@Input() variable1: boolean;
@Input() variable2: boolean;
```

appcomponent.html

```
<button (click)="Activate_variable1">Activate Variable1</button>
<button (click)="Activate variable2">Activate Variable2</button>
<child-component [variable1]="variable1" [variable2]="variable2"></child-component>
<child-component [variable1]="variable1" [variable2]="varibale2"></child-component>
```

appcomponent.ts

```
variable1 = false;
variable2 = false;

Activate_variable1(){
this.variable1 = true;
this.variable2 = false;
}

Actiavate_variable2(){
this.variable2 = true;
this.variable1 = false;
}
```

So, here I may get output as container 1 twice or container 2 twice but what I'm looking here is Container 1 and Container 2 as output (one selector should give container 1 as output and the other selector should give container 2 as output). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for the above example (i.e. you have only two child components, and your variables are of boolean type) would be reversing values for the variables

```
<button (click)="Activate_variable1">Activate Variable1</button>
<button (click)="Activate variable2">Activate Variable2</button>
<child-component [variable1]="variable1" [variable2]="variable2"></child-component>
<child-component [variable1]="!variable1" [variable2]="!variable2"></child-component>
```

Also, you can simplify your code for the child component by removing === comparison if the only possible values for that variable are true and false, i.e.:

```
<div *ngIf="variable1">
  Container 1
</div>

<div *ngIf="variable2">
   Container 2
</div>
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, If we use the selector only once we can easily achieve that but in my case I have to use the selector twice and achieve different outputs. Is there a way to achieve different outputs with the same selector using twice?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your problem, please check the modified answer

Comment: but when an app reloads the 2nd selector gets activated because the variable1 and variable2 which are initially in false becomes true. therefore as an output Contiainer 1 and Container 2 we will get. This should not be the case one should see the output only on clicking the button